# Move cell brackets on the left of a notebook

Tags: notebooks

Is there a way to put cell brackets on the left of a current notebook? In order to visualize better a notebook structure. An image is added to illustrate the point.[image]

Comment: Your question may be put [on-hold](https://goo.gl/jXYaiD) because it may be considered a [duplicate](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/duplicates) and therefore [off-topic](https://goo.gl/bnZVrD). Please [edit] your question if you consider this is a mistake and give great emphasis to what they did not answer in the other question pointed out by Carl Lange. Please don't be discouraged by that cleaning up policy. Your questions are and will be most welcomed. Learn about [good questions here](https://goo.gl/BqKxV3).

Comment: By the way, welcome to Mma.SE! start by **taking the [tour] now**. It **helps us to help you** when you write an [excellent question](https://goo.gl/BqKxV3). You can always [edit](https://goo.gl/ELLhTX) if improvable, to show due diligence, give brief context, include **minimal working example** of code and data in **[formatted form](https://goo.gl/ELLhTX)**. As you receive **give back**, vote and answer questions, keep the site useful, be kind, correct mistakes and share what you have learned.